# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, inflate-exception

I am integrating facebook login in an android app with firebase.
The app crash when the login activity starts and shows the following error

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.environer.behappy/com.environer.behappy.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

**In new facebook SDK there is no need to initialize the sdk by calling FacebookSdk.initializeSdk() since it will be auto initialized**

**I have imported the login button using com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton**

**I also have called onActivityResult on CallBackManager**

My Code is below

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    configureGoogleSignIn();
}
@OnClick(R.id.button_facebook)void facebookSignIn(){

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.loginCancel), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.welcomeText) + user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == SIGNIN_CODE){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
        else{
            //Google signin Failed
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

}
```

My XML Code

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewGmail"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewGmail"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewGmail"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
```

Comment: have you tried initializing the SDK anyway (I know that the docs says there is no need to but try)?

Comment: @HammadNasir Android Studio shows that 'sdkInitialize()' is deprecated

Comment: have you tried running the app after initializing the SDK?

Comment: @HammadNasir Done bro!!
Why I need to initialize the sdk since its mention in official documentation that sdk will be auto initialized and why android studio shows that its deprecated  ?

Comment: okay, cool! Can you paste your `logcat` here?

Comment: @HammadNasir Current logcat or with error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150222/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-mohammad-adil).